# Error Compiling Netty latest (Master) version

Tags: maven, netty

I would like to test some of the latest features locate in netty Master branch at github.
(`git://github.com/netty/netty.git`)

I'm doing the following steps:

1. Open new empty directory on my local machine
2. Type `git init`
3. Type `git pull git://github.com/netty/netty.git`
4. Compile pom.xml using maven as follow: `mvn clean package`

I now get the following compliation error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.855s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jan 08 12:14:21 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/176M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project netty: Compilation failure: Compilation
 failure:
[ERROR] \tradair\tools\netty\src\main\java\io\netty\util\internal\LegacyLinkedTransferQueue.java:[655,61] type parameters of <E>E cannot be determined; no uniqu
e maximal instance exists for type variable E with upper bounds E,java.lang.Object
[ERROR] \tradair\tools\netty\src\main\java\io\netty\util\internal\LegacyLinkedTransferQueue.java:[739,53] type parameters of <E>E cannot be determined; no uniqu
e maximal instance exists for type variable E with upper bounds E,java.lang.Object
[ERROR] \tradair\tools\netty\src\main\java\io\netty\util\internal\LegacyLinkedTransferQueue.java:[827,57] type parameters of <E>E cannot be determined; no uniqu
e maximal instance exists for type variable E with upper bounds E,java.lang.Object
[ERROR] \tradair\tools\netty\src\main\java\io\netty\util\internal\LegacyLinkedTransferQueue.java:[880,65] type parameters of <E>E cannot be determined; no uniqu
e maximal instance exists for type variable E with upper bounds E,java.lang.Object
```

Can you please advise what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't see such an error when I tried it.  It ends in a failure however not because of compilation errors as in your case.  The failure I see are in the _unit tests_.  I am using Maven 3.0.3 with Java 6.  A minor side note: The idiomatic recipe for downloading and building netty is to simply:`git clone git://github.com/netty/netty.git`.  You don't have to `git init` and `git pull`.

Comment: You are correct about git!!! Any other ideas on how to compile the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedTransferQueue back-porting was done recently in master, so you better try with latest version of JDK 6, (>= 1.6.0_25, [a compiler bug?](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6302954))

Comment: Great works with jdk1.6.0_30 but now I get another error `an 9, 2012 1:49:20 PM io.netty.handler.ssl.AbstractSocketSslEchoTest
ARNING: Unexpected exception from the client side
ava.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed` any idea what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

That's a java bug (I hit it before also). Upgrade to latest jdk and it will work. I don't recall what exactly version of java was giving the problems

Comment: Great works with jdk1.6.0_30 but now I get another error an 9, 2012 1:49:20 PM io.netty.handler.ssl.AbstractSocketSslEchoTest ARNING: Unexpected exception from the client side ava.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed any idea what to next.